# How to save hibernate object in coherence Cache

Tags: hibernate, caching, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

In our application earlier we used to save a hibernate object in runtime cache(It is not second level cache  it is a singleton java class which use a key value pair to save java object) . Now we are planning to move our application to a cluster environment (weblogic 12C), so to make the cache work in two node clusters we are planning to use oracle coherence. But the problem is the hibernate object is confusing us. Hibernate object is a complex object and holding a hierarchy of too many child classes. How we can save that hibernate object in coherence cache?

As per complex object saving process in coherence we need to create POF classes . Here the hibernate object is  big enough for implementing all POF classes and portable set . So this will be very hectic job for us to set the values for all POF object parallel to hibernate POJO classes. Even we are bit concerned about performance issues for this. Is there any other way to save the hibernate object in coherence. Do we need to implement second level cache with coherence for this ? Please help us which will be the best way for this. Using second level cache can we save object at the time of saving object in database? You can share sample code and configuration if you have any for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see to the option where Coherence doesn't persist entities to the DB. Let your legacy code to do it and update the cache. 
In such case you won't need any additional code on 'Coherence' side. Coherence will store binary representation of the Entities.

It leaves you to create POF mappings in your application code, here you can try to add POF annotations on the existing Hibernate object instead of creating similar structure.